# How do I extract lines from one file containing a list of words from another file?

Tags: awk, grep

I've tried all the suggestions on this website and the output is incomplete.

File 1 showing list of proteins I'd like to search in file 2 and extract the complete set of lines containing the information I need.

```
Q14157
Q14444
P23246
Q96EP5
Q9UN86
Q14011
Q7Z739
Q9Y383
Q96I24
Q9NP61
P29558
P51116
P00441
Q2TBT7
Q9NZI8
```

File 2 containing (incomplete paste here on this section) the info to be extracted from the list in file 1.

```
P21796  260 Phosphoserine   S   1
P21796  266 N6-acetyllysine K   4
P21796  266 Ubiquitination  K   3
P21796  274 N6-acetyllysine K   1
P21796  274 Ubiquitination  K   3
P18848  45  Sumoylation K   1
P18848  45  Ubiquitination  K   2
P18848  53  Sumoylation K   1
P18848  55  Ubiquitination  K   2
P18848  69  Phosphoserine   S   4
P18848  75  Ubiquitination  K   2
P18848  88  Ubiquitination  K   2
P18848  107 Phosphothreonine    T   1
P18848  114 Phosphothreonine    T   1
P18848  115 Phosphothreonine    T   1
P18848  119 Phosphothreonine    T   1
P18848  213 Phosphothreonine    T   1
P18848  215 Phosphoserine   S   1
P18848  219 Phosphoserine   S   4
P18848  224 Phosphoserine   S   3
P18848  231 Phosphoserine   S   1
P18848  235 Phosphoserine   S   1
P18848  245 Phosphoserine   S   3
P18848  248 Phosphoserine   S   3
P18848  267 Sumoylation K   1
P18848  277 Ubiquitination  K   1
P18848  293 Phosphothreonine    T   1
P18848  295 Phosphotyrosine Y   1
P18848  335 Ubiquitination  K   2
P18848  343 N6-acetyllysine K   1
P18848  348 N6-acetyllysine K   1
P23246  7   Dimethylation   R   1
P23246  7   Omega-N-methylarginine  R   2
P23246  8   Phosphoserine   S   3
P23246  9   Asymmetric dimethylarginine R   1
P23246  9   Dimethylation   R   1
P23246  9   Methylation R   1
P23246  9   Omega-N-methylarginine  R   3
P23246  19  Dimethylation   R   1
P23246  19  Methylation R   1
P23246  19  Omega-N-methylarginine  R   2
P23246  25  Dimethylation   R   1
P23246  25  Methylation R   1
P23246  25  Omega-N-methylarginine  R   2
P23246  32  Dimethylation   R   1
P23246  32  Methylation R   1
P23246  33  Phosphoserine   S   8
Q14011  17  Phosphothreonine    T   1
Q14011  21  Phosphoserine   S   1
Q14011  33  Phosphoserine   S   1
Q14011  47  Methylation R   1
Q14011  71  Phosphoserine   S   3
Q14011  84  Ubiquitination  K   2
Q14011  94  Dimethylation   R   1
```

Comment: The `awk` script at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/458452/133219 will work for your unsorted input, otherwise a `join` solution would work. Don't try to use a `grep` solution as it'll be fragile.

Comment: not sure how to apply this to my file 1 and file 2: $ awk 'NR==FNR {a[$1]++; next} $1 in a' words myfile

Comment: You have 2 options - `awk '...' file1 file2` or `awk '...' file2 file1`. If you can't tell at a glance which to use, why not try both and see which works?

Comment: Thanks. I tried it and it says that awk cannot open file 1 source line number 1. Help please :)

Comment: The problem which is left has little to do with your original question which is a clear duplicate. You should create a new question about your problem with the `awk` call.

Answer (score 3):

`grep -f file1 file2` should search in `file2` for all the patterns in `file1` and print the matching lines. (With matches anywhere, though, so this might yield false positives if a protein name in some way appears after the first column.) Since you want to match fixed strings, you could also add `-F`.

Comment: That would incorrectly find partial matches in the target field and matches in the wrong fields.

Comment: True, but judging from the example data, this shouldn't be a problem for the OP.

Comment: That is true, but I had the impression that the idea for this site is to have answers that can be generalized. Perhaps you should at least mention the limitation in your answer.

Comment: I only get partial matches...

Comment: @user1250704 What is missing? With your test data I get the last 23 lines (the ones with P23246 and Q14011), which seems ok to me.

Answer (score 0):

One approach to this problem is to escape all the regex characters in file1
and in the next step constrain the string from both ends. Note that the ordering of the steps is imp.

This can be referred to as a `hybrid regex` approach wherein the actual string to be matched has all it's regex BRE chars escaped away so that it becomes a literal string whilst in the peripheries we place regex chars to constrain the match as a first field.

```
$ < file1 \
    sed -e '
      s:[[\.*^$]:\\&:g
      s/.*/^&[[:blank:]]/
'  | grep -f - file2
```

*Step-1 => render the string in file1 as a pure string vis-a-vis grep using BRE expressions.

*Step-2 => constrain the above escaped string on the left to the beginning of line and on the right to a blank character.

- Imp note: We are escaping the BRE regex characters. So do not invoke `grep` with `-E`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below awk command

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next}($1 in a){print $0}' file1 file2
```